# Match element ignoring namespace

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml from a service:

```
<GetClass_RS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Class xmlns="http://www.company.com/erp/worker/soa/2013/03">
    <student>Jack</student>
    <student>Harry</student>
    <student>Rebecca</student>
    <teacher>Mr. Bean</teacher>
  </Class>
</GetClass_RS>
```

I want to match Class/student like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Class/student">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is due to the class's namespace the match doesn't work:

```
<Class xmlns="http://www.company.com/erp/worker/soa/2013/03">
```

I would like to ignore the namespace in the match.

Comment: Why do you want to ignore it, rather than use it?  Is the namespace unreliable somehow?

Comment: Good point, I suppose I don't need to ignore it. I just need to match the element with the namespace and I'm not sure how since it's not been given an alias as I've seen in other examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Good point, I suppose I don't need to ignore it. I just need to match
>   the element with the namespace

First of all, note that if a namespace is declared like this:

```
<Class xmlns="http://www.company.com/erp/worker/soa/2013/03">
```

Then it applies to all its child elements, too. In other words, in your XML input, `student` and `teacher` elements are also in that namespace.

If elements in your input XML have a namespace, you have to mention that particular namespace in your XSLT stylesheet as well. The following line:

```
xmlns:class="http://www.company.com/erp/worker/soa/2013/03"
```

Declares this namespace and defines a *prefix*. Prefixing an element is like a shorthand way of declaring its namespace.

**Stylesheet**

I have added a template that matches `teacher` elements. Otherwise, their text content is output via the default behaviour of your XSLT processor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:class="http://www.company.com/erp/worker/soa/2013/03">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="class:Class/class:student">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="class:teacher"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p xmlns:class="http://www.company.com/erp/worker/soa/2013/03">Jack</p>
<p xmlns:class="http://www.company.com/erp/worker/soa/2013/03">Harry</p>
<p xmlns:class="http://www.company.com/erp/worker/soa/2013/03">Rebecca</p>
```

As suggested by @michael.hor257k, if you add `exclude-result-prefixes="class"` to the `stylesheet` element, the elements are output without a namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>Jack</p>
<p>Harry</p>
<p>Rebecca</p>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should add `exclude-result-prefixes="class"` to the stylesheet element.

Comment: Good suggestion. I'll add it as a possible improvement (depends on the OP's intent).